# JQuery Mobile hardware back button press in android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

Can anyone give me the example of hardware back button press event listener in android device on particular page?

I am using this code but not working.

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function(){

    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){                                   
        if($.mobile.activePage.is('#dept-list-page')){  
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("back  button pressed");
            navigator.app.exitApp();        
        }else{
            history.back();
        }
     }, false);
});
```

In Webview, I am using keydown method.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if (webView != null)
                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                    return true;
                }
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

But many html pages generated dynamically in a single webview and I want to check this on particular page.

Comment: @BasVanStein Sir, cordova is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `phonegap` (cordova), which seems to be the case, you need to set the `eventlistener` after the `deviceReady` like

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function onBackKeyDown(e){
    if($.mobile.activePage.is('#dept-list-page')){  
        //if the page checking doesnt work try:
        // $.mobile.activePage.attr("id") == '#dept-list-page'
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("back  button pressed");
        navigator.app.exitApp();

    }else{
        history.back();
    }
}
```

If you use an Android `Webview` you should handle the backbutton in your Android code instead by using something like

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed (){
    if(webView.canGoBack()) webView.goBack();
    else super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: I am not using Cordova or phonegap. It's a hybrid application.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much.